# Launching the application from an url in the browser for BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing one application where i will launch a url in the browser from which i will launch my application.

Suppose if i will click `google.com`, and press **enter**, it will launch my application. For that i tried with the `HttpFilterRegistry` API.

For reference i am using the **HTTPFilterDemo** application. But currently while launching the app, i am getting the `NullPointerException`.

I wrote the below code i the `openFilter` Method:

```java
 public Connection openFilter(String name, int mode, boolean timeouts) throws IOException {
    Logger.out("Protocol", "it is inside the openFilter method");
    _url = name.substring(2);
    _requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    _responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    _responseHeaders.setProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html");
    Logger.out("Protocol", "here it is come ::::44444444");
    final int modHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("AppLaunchBrowser");
    Logger.out("Protocol", "here is the module handle:::" + modHandle);
    final ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(modHandle);
    final ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor(apDes[0], new String[] {});
    Logger.out("Protocol", "here is the app descriptor:::" + appDescriptor);
    try {
        final int appCode = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(appDescriptor, true);
        Logger.out("Protocol", "here is the app code:::" + appCode);
    } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // }
    return this;
}
```

And in the application class i am creating alternative entry point and using like below:

```java
  public class AppLaunch extends UiApplication{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Logger.out("AppLaunch", args+"length of the arguments::::" +args.length);
        if((args != null) && (args.length > 0) && (args[0].equals("background")))
        {
            Logger.out("AppLaunch", "in the alternate entry point");
//          Logger.out("AppLaunch", args+"length of the arguments::::" +args.length);
            HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter("www.google.co.in", "com.innominds.ca", false);


        }
        else 
        {
            Logger.out("AppLaunch", "Inside the Applaunch");
            AppLaunch theApp = new AppLaunch();
            theApp.requestForeground();
            Logger.out("AppLaunch", "created the app launch object");
            theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
//          Logger.out("AppLaunch", "in the alternate entry point");
//          HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter("www.google.co.in", "com.innominds.ca", false);
        }
    }

    public AppLaunch()
    {
        checkPermissions();
        showTestScreen();
    }


    private void checkPermissions()
    {

        ApplicationPermissionsManager apm = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();
        ApplicationPermissions original = apm.getApplicationPermissions();

        if(original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_BROWSER_FILTER) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW)
        {
            // All of the necessary permissions are currently available
            return;
        }

        ApplicationPermissions permRequest = new ApplicationPermissions();
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_BROWSER_FILTER);

        boolean acceptance = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance().invokePermissionsRequest(permRequest);

        if(acceptance)
        {
            // User has accepted all of the permissions
            return;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void showTestScreen()
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new AppLaunchScreen());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the line at which the NPE is thrown?

Comment: i am not getting where it is throwing. because evry log in the code is executing except in AppLaunch class where i am creating the alternate entry point..

Comment: I am trying to debug it..but it is telling debug file is missing..So i am not able to find out the exact location of the NPE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve this issue. Actually NPE is coming in some other callback methods because i was implementing the FilterBaseInterface.